# Android App with Google Map is only showing map of Africa and will not load users current location?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I have an Android App that uses Google Maps and Google play  when the user downloads the app and brings up the map the default view of Africa stays up and will not go to the users location.  When I built the app I pulled up the SHA-1 from my release keystore and added it to the Google API Console which gave me my Release key which I added to my AndroidManifest.xml.  When I run the app from debug mode or the Google Play the map brings up my current location with a route of where the user needs to go.  Any suggestions?

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eema"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <permission

        android:name="com.eema.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.eema" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.eema.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <!--
         The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.





    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>     
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<!--         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.eema.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.eema.MapViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.eema.NoConnectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_no_connection" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.eema.ShelterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shelter" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.eema.FuelStopActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fuel_stop" >
       </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.eema.DirectionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_directions" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.eema.EvacRouteTableActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_evac_route_table" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the users location isn't reaady when you set it. The default position for the map is over europe and africa so if thats what you are seeing then its probably that your user location is null or empty.

Comment: How could the users position be null or empty?

Comment: The location services can take time to get the correct location of the user. If the location services are not ready when you try to get the users location they will return either an empty location or null depending on the method used.